# Showing a norm-induced metric is indeed a metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

In my first graduate school course (a course in metric spaces and general topology), we were given the following example in class:

> Let $(V,d)$ be a normed vector space such that $d : V \times V \to [0, \infty)$ defined by $d(\vec{x},\vec{y}) := \|\vec{x} - \vec{y}\|$ (the magnitude of the difference of the two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$).

I am aware that a norm $d$ on a vector space $V$ induces a metric and I wanted to show on my own time after class that this is, indeed, a metric. Showing the first two requirements for a map $d$ to be a metric on a set (which in this case is a vector space) were a breeze. Showing that triangle inequality holds however, has proven to be difficult - at least as far as I can see.

---

**My Thoughts:**

Since we have to show that $\forall \vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z} \in V$: $$d(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) \leq d(\vec{x},\vec{z}) + d(\vec{z}, \vec{y}),$$ or rewritten as: $$\|\vec{x} - \vec{y}\| \leq \|\vec{x} - \vec{z}\| + \|\vec{z} - \vec{y}\|,$$ and since $d$ is a norm, can we apply the triangle inequality for norms to get the desired result that $\|\vec{x} - \vec{y}\| \leq \|\vec{x} - \vec{z}\| + \|\vec{z} - \vec{y}\|$  (for example for vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ of some arbitrary vector space $M: \|\vec{a} + \vec{b}\| \leq \|\vec{a}\| + \|\vec{b}\|$)?

Going off of that notation: $$ \begin{align*} \|(\vec{x} - \vec{z}) +(\vec{z} - \vec{y})\| &\leq \|\vec{x} - \vec{z}\| + \|\vec{z} - \vec{y}\| \\ \|\vec{x} - \vec{z} +\vec{z} - \vec{y}\| &\leq \|\vec{x} - \vec{z}\| + \|\vec{z} - \vec{y}\| \\ \|\vec{x} - \vec{y}\| &\leq \|\vec{x} - \vec{z}\| + \|\vec{z} - \vec{y}\| \\ d(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) &\leq d(\vec{x},\vec{z}) + d(\vec{z}, \vec{y}), \end{align*}$$ which would conclude our proof that the triangle inequality holds and $d$ is in fact a metric.

I believe this is incorrect as it feels too easy and that I am missing something. Any criticism is welcome.

Comment: (1) There's some notation that's not what I'm used to- "Let $(V,d)$ be a normed vector space such that $d : V \times V \to [0, \infty)$ defined by...", a norm is a function $V\to[0,\infty)$, but a metric is a funtion $V\times V\to [0,\infty)$. So it seems you have it mixed. I would write $(V,d)$ for a metric space and $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ for a normed vector space. (2) "we proceeded to prove that this is a norm on $V$" I can't understand this, because you were given that it was a normed vector space. There should be nothing to prove. But (3) it would seem that your proof is correct

Comment: @CalvinKhor - Thank you for all the feedback and verification. I will be sure next time to check my grammar and use of terminology!

Comment: But the proof is really just that easy.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith - alas, overthinking got the best of me! Glad to hear i'm on the right track in my thinking.